# Uploading file to Evernote using Delphi

Tags: delphi, evernote

I am developing an application in Delphi. I need to upload files to Evernote using rest api. Is there any Evernote rest api available to upload files from Delphi?.

Comment: Evernote has a REST API. Whether it has provisions for uploading files can be found in [their documentation](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/). Any REST API can be used with Delphi.

Comment: But maybe you meant to ask: *Do they have a Delphi SDK*? That same page tells you: **no**. But nothing should stop you from writing code that consumes their REST interface.

Comment: (Turns out they even have a COM interface, but I suggest you forget that and use REST)

Comment: Can you provide me Authorization end point, Token End point and Redirect URI. When i tried with "https://sandbox.evernote.com/OAuth.action" i am getting Missing required oauth parameter "oauth_token"

Comment: Why did you not have a look into their docs? https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php

Answer (score 0):

Evernote's API is not REST-based. It's based on a binary standard called Thrift, which requires the creation of client-side bindings in order to make calls to it. These bindings have been created for many languages and bundled into SDKs, but Delphi is not one of them.

It should be possible for you to generate your own Delphi bindings given the API definition, but this is fairly advanced work and given your comment re the OAuth stuff, I'd suggest that you find an alternate way of achieving your goals, like invoking the Evernote client application (via COM on Windows or AppleScript on Mac) and passing data that way. (You can Google for or open new questions about either approach.)